# Smooth scroll elements inside child div which is below header

Tags: javascript, jquery

So here is the fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/malakar369/y5Lppeg0/8/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
   $('.custom-click').on('click', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var href = $(this).attr('href');
     var current_div = $(href);
     var animateTo = $(href).position().top ;
     console.log(animateTo);
     $('#main-height-container').animate({scrollTop: animateTo},"slow");
  });
});
```

It works if my div is at the top of the page. However, since it is not at the top i am having and extensive amount of issue. Could any of you guys could have a look at it and help me out.

Thanks

Comment: What is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(href).position().top is in window coordinates

Try this

```
var animateTo = $("#main-height-container").scrollTop() - $("#main-height-container").position().top + $(href).position().top;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y5Lppeg0/9/

Comment: Sorry for late response. Had to modify your code a little bit. And it worked Thanks :)